# Seating plans on airplanes

Tags: air-travel, seating

I just web checked in for my next flight. Out of curiosity I checked the seating plane. Normally, all the rows have 6 seats. 3 on the right side and 3 on the left side. But some rows have only 2 seats on each side. What could be the reason for that? And would these seats be a good or a bad choice?

Comment: Can you provide some images? May be there are just emergency exits there?

Comment: I'll check if I can log into it again

Comment: I can't log in again, but in this case it is an A321 and the rows are around row 9.

Comment: Which airline is this and what's the flight number? That'll help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the type of plane and even on the company. These could be seats in first or business class rather than economy class. You can only choose these seats if you have paid for them ... On the other these could be seats next to an emergency exit. You usually have some extra room for your legs there. On the other hand, you cannot store your hand-luggage under the seat. The trays are in the armrest. On some planes this means that the seats have a reduced width. Moreover, in case of trouble, you are expected to handle the emergency exit. This also means that you need to be physically able to do this. I have once been refused such a seat, because I had a splint on my foot due to an accident.

I suggest you have a look at [SeatGuru](http://www.seatguru.com/). There you will find seating plans and comments on the good and bad seats.

Comment: Its strange. According to that plan I've chosen business class seats. Really weird.

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: @Roflcoptr not so weird. Many airlines have taken to reclassing the last few rows of business class as economy with the reduction in business class traffic over the last several years (economic trouble, many companies no longer allowing it, etc.). I've had such seats myself several times. Business class seat (and legroom!), economy class service.

Answer (score 5):

According this scheme:
[image]
There are emergency exits near row 8-9.

I think that's why there are some restrictions on this. But I don't think this is bad place.
On this scheme green is for good place, yellow is for not very good place, and red is for the bad place.